# Ширина элемента html шире окна браузера

Tags: html, reactjs

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при разработке приложения на реакте, в окне браузера Opera блок body шире окна браузера на какой-то странный процент? В
Chrome все нормально. Для примера, при ширине окна браузера 1840px, элемент body равен 2044.44px, при уменьшении ширины окна браузера, уменьшается и разница между шириной окна и блоком body. Если выбрать готовое устройство в браузере, то ширина сразу же становится адекватной. Документ пустой. Если просто открыть index.html файл в браузере, то с шириной все в порядке.

Comment: Никто не будет гадать, как устроена у вас вёрстка. Дополните вопрос примером кода.

Comment: box-sizing: border-box используете?

Comment: Quazimoda, Вы внимательно прочитали вопрос? Написано же, что документ ПУСТ! Свежесозданный проект реакта.

Comment: Iurii, стили те, которые идут сразу после создания проекта реакт, ничего не менял.